# How to unmarshal JSON with unnamed fields with JAXB Moxy

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey, jackson, moxy

While unmarshalling this json string:

```
[
    {
        "id": "123"
    },
    {
        "id": "456"
    }
]
```

I get this error:

> An exception occured while executing the Java class. null:
>   InvocationTargetException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to
>   com.example.Ids

How do I correctly unmarshal the above JSON string into Ids Java object using Moxy?  I would also like to know how to do this using Jackson (for Jersey response).

These are the classes:

### Ids.java

```
package com.example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Ids {
    @XmlList
    private List<Id> ids;

    public List<Id> getIds()
    {
        return ids;
    }

    public void setIds(List<Id> ids)
    {
        this.ids = ids;
    }
}
```

### Id.java

```
package com.example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Id {
    private String id;

    public String getId() {
    return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
    }
}
```

### App.java

```
package com.example;

import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.MarshallerProperties;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.UnmarshallerProperties;

import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
    String resp = "[ {\"id\" : \"123\" }, {\"id\" : \"456\" } ]";
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
    properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
    properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Ids.class}, properties);

    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(resp);

    StreamSource json = new StreamSource(reader);
    Ids foo = unmarshaller.unmarshal(json, Ids.class).getValue();
    Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the underground. But in my opinion Ids class is redundant here.

So you can simply unmarshal that array into List. Or you will have to change JSON.

Without Ids it will looks like:

```
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[]{Id.class}, properties);
    Unmarshaller um = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(resp);
    List<Id> ids = (List<Id>)um.unmarshal(new StreamSource(reader), Id.class).getValue();
```